# Trouble in declaring pointer before implementation of class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, compilation

```
ConverterProxy *pthis;

ConverterProxy::ConverterProxy() {
    pthis = this;
    converter::callWhenUpdated(&CallBack);
}

void ConverterProxy::CallBack() {

    pthis->updatedOutside();

}

ConverterProxy::~ConverterProxy() {

    delete pthis;

}
```

Header:

```
class ConverterProxy
{

    Q_OBJECT


public:

    ConverterProxy();
    ~ConverterProxy();

    static void CallBack();

signals:
    void updatedOutside();

};
```

This throws an error:`undefined reference to 'vtable for ConverterProxy'`

When I put `ConverterProxy *pthis;` after implementation of constructor, that error disappears.

What is the cause of this weird situation?

Comment: Please post the smallest sample code you can come up with that compiles **and shows the problem**. This snippet has too much code elided.

Comment: @PeteBecker Was that sarcasm ?:D

Comment: No, it's advice to help you to help us to help you. I'd suggest following it and posting a [Small, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The error makes no sense with the code you have posted. Please post a complete example.

Comment: Without having enough insight into your problem (providing the class declaration might be helpful): This linker error generally means that one or more virtual functions that are involved with the type ConverterProxy have no implementation.

Comment: @Bojangles This is not a huge code obviously and I am not missing anything except the header file, so...

Comment: @gerritzijlstra I have posted the header file, though I don't think it is helpful... I dont have any virtual functions

Comment: You haven't added any virtual functions - but maybe Q_OBJECT does. It's hard to help without a full working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in QT, but let me guess how to fix your problem.
There is some QT-related stuff in your code:

```
Q_OBJECT
```

I have no idea what it contains; however judging from your error it may add something about virtual functions to your class, even though you didn't have any. Try removing that stuff from your class.

Alternatively, if you really need that `Q_OBJECT` bit, try inheriting from QObject:

```
class ConverterProxy: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
};
```

There is some documentation, which hints that `Q_OBJECT` must be used together with inheritance from `QObject`: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/moc.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't `delete pthis` in your destructor. Your object is already being destroyed.